# Обращение или нет?

Tags: запятые

"Не желает ли Ваше Святейшество чаю?"

"Ваше Святейшество" - это обращение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, грамматически это не обращение. 
Здесь это подлежащее.

Вообще такие "косвенные обращения", характерные для общения с высокопоставленными особами (а в некоторых языках, в польском, например, пригодные вообще почти в любой ситуации), и призваны заменить прямые обращения к такой персоне, которое могло бы рассматриваться как неуважительное. Но это уже вопрос этикета, дело тонкое.

Answer (score 1):

Нет.

Почему:

Не жела**ет** ли (**он**) Ваше Святейшество чаю? - нет обращения. || Так как можно подставить "он".

Не жела**ете** ли, (**Вы**) Ваше Святейшество, чаю? - обращение (с обособлением). || При обращениях всегда можно подставить ***ты/вы***.